# Error relación muchos a muchos en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo un error con una relación muchos a muchos en Larvel 5.5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Relaciono una tabla `interventions` con otra `patients` con tabla pivote `user_interventions`. A continuación adjunto las migraciones y los modelos.

**intenventions**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('interventions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->integer('professional_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('professional_id')->references('id')->on('professionals');
        $table->string('patient_record')->nullable;
        $table->foreign('patient_record')->references('record')->on('patients');
        $table->integer('type_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');
        $table->integer('place_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('place_id')->references('id')->on('places');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**El modelo interventions**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Intervention extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['date', 'professional_id', 'patient_record', 'type_id', 'place_id', 'description'];

    public function patients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Patient', 'user_interventions', 'interventions_id', 'patient_record');
    }

    public function professionals()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Professional::class, 'professional_id');
    }

    public function types()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Type::class, 'type_id');
    }

    public function places()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Place::class, 'place_id');
    }
}
```

**patients**

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('patients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('record', 7)->index();
        $table->string('name', 75);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**El modelo patients**

```
    class Patient extends Model
{
    public function interventions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Intervention', 'user_interventions', 'patient_record', 'interventions_id');
    }

}
```

**El código que utilizo para pasar datos a la vista**

```
public function createUsers(Request $request)
{
        $intervention_id = $request->intervention_id;
        if ($intervention_id) {
    $patients = Patient::all();
    $interventiongrup = Intervention::where('id', $intervention_id)->with('professionals')->with('types')->with('places')->get();
    $intervention_users = Intervention::where('id', $intervention_id)->with('patients')->get();

    return view('interventions.grupal')->with(compact('patients', 'interventiongrup', 'intervention_users',$intervention_id));
  }
}
```

**El código que utilizo para mostrar los datos en la vista**

```
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Usuarios</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach ($intervention_users->patients as $intervention_patient)
        <tr>
          <td width="450px">{{ $intervention_patient->record }} {{ $intervention_patient->name }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Espero su ayuda, gracias.

En primer lugar lo hago como me dices pero me sigue dando error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui pongo el modelo `Patient`

```
class Patient extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['record', 'name'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'record';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = 'false';

    public function interventions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Intervention', 'user_interventions', 'patient_record', 'interventions_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    // public function user_interventions()
    // {
    //   return $this->hasMany(User_intervention::class);
    // }
}
```

Y el código del controlador que devuelve el valor:

```
public function createUsers(Request $request)
{
    $intervention_id = $request->intervention_id;
    if ($intervention_id) {
    $patients = Patient::all();
    $interventiongrup = Intervention::where('id', $intervention_id)->with('professionals')->with('types')->with('places')->get();
    $intervention_users = Intervention::where('id', $intervention_id)->with('patients')->get();
    return view('interventions.grupal')->with(compact('patients', 'interventiongrup', 'intervention_users', $intervention_id));
  }
}
```

Y el código de la vista:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Usuarios</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @if ($intervention_users)
    @foreach ($intervention_users as $intervention_patient)
    <tr>
      @if ($intervention_patient)
      <td width="450px">{{ $intervention_patient->patients->record }} {{ $intervention_patient->patients->name }}</td>
      @endif
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  @endif
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Y como he puesto en la respuesta, al mostrar con `dd` si que aparece la relación. No se si puede tener algo que ver el pasarlo con `compact`.

Comment: Falta el `id` de `patients`

Comment: El `id` de `patients` es el campo `record` .

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que en lugar de llamar `id` a la clave primaria de `patients` la has llamado `record`. Laravel, si no se le dice otra cosa, cuando crea los `join` usa el término `id` como clave primaria. Al usar otro término y no informarle da el error de que no encuentra la columna `patients.id`. Para solucionar esto hay que informar en el modelo patients la nueva clave:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'record';
```

**Editado**

Primero "separas" las intervenciones y después ya puedes obtener datos de cada intervanción.

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Usuarios</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($intervention_users as $intervention_patient)
        <tr>
            <td width="450px">{{ $intervention_patient->patients->record }} {{ $intervention_patient->patients->name }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. He hecho el cambio que me has sugerido y ya no sale ese error, pero desde `interventions` no me devuelve `patients`. Me dice que no encuentra la propiedad `patients`en la colección.

Comment: Porque estás queriendo obtener una `collection` de otra `collection` (para entendernos). Añado en la respuesta

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, me dice que no reconoce la propiedad `record`, pero si lo hago con `dd($intervention_users);` si que me devuelve el array correspondiente, mira lo que sale:

Comment: Con `dd(intervention_users)` sale esto:                                     Collection {#239 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
     #attributes: array:9 [▼
     "id" => 92
     "date" => "2018-02-19"
     "professional_id" => 4
     "type_id" => 9
     "place_id" => 1
     "description" => "Musicoterapia"
     #relations: array:1 [▼
        "patients" => Collection {#252 ▼
          #items: array:2 [▼
              #attributes: array:4 [▼
                "record" => "0004/01"
                "name" => "María Jesus"

Comment: Modificado patient por patients

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por intentar ayudarme, he vuelto a revisar la documentación de Laravel y me he dado cuenta que utilizaba `find` para buscar datos, en lugar de `where`, he probado y me funciona asi:

**Controlador:**

```
public function createUsers(Request $request)
{
   $intervention_id = $request->intervention_id;
   if ($intervention_id) {
      $patients = Patient::all();
      $interventiongrup = Intervention::where('id', $intervention_id)->with('professionals')->with('types')->with('places')->get();
      $intervention_users = Intervention::find($intervention_id);
      return view('interventions.grupal')->with(compact('patients', 'interventiongrup', 'intervention_users', $intervention_id));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo tengo el mismo problema pero ya me salio de una manera buscando un solo dato y trayendo todos sus campos relacionados.

Un Usuario tiene muchos cursos ese es mi ejemplo

el controlador quedo asi

```
public function index()
{

   $alumnos=Alumno::findOrFail(101);



   //dd($alumnos->cursos);


   return view('front.index',compact('alumnos'));
}
```

busco al usuario 101

mi modelo es:

```
public function cursos()
{ 
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Curso');  
}
```

La salida en blate quedo asi

```
<div class="panel-body">
   Alumno:  {{ $alumnos->nombre }}
   <hr>

   @foreach ($alumnos->cursos as  $curso )

    Curso: {{ $curso->nombre }}

   @endforeach                 

</div>
```

La salida se ve así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todavía no me sale cuando quiero traer a todos los alumnos, y que me muestre todos los cursos de cada alumno.

Espero que te funcione y a lo mejor tu si sabes como hacerlo con todos los alumnos si sabes pues pediría tu ayuda gracias